# Image not displayed in the browser

Tags: html

Image stored outside webroot not getting displayed.
Below is the code snippet:

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="/Applications/XAMPP/im/tesla.jpg" alt="TESLA">
</body>
```

Comment: Can Provide the folder sturcture of your project ??

Comment: "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/" is the root.

Comment: @AnkitaSansarwal are you using IIS server, apache, or...?

Comment: you have to put your things inside the htdocs cz htdocs is your root.

Comment: i m using apache server as localhost

Comment: i have purposely put images outside root, just having troubling displaying it on the webpage.

Comment: Put your images inside your document root, unless there's a valid reason not to do.

Answer (score 0):

if /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/yourwebsite go
2x back to  get in xampp folder and then follow folder that you need

```
<html>
 <body>
 <img src="../../im/tesla.jpg" alt="TESLA">
 </body>
</html>
```